# Brownie Not Using Etherscan API

Tags: python, web3py, brownie

I have brownie installed on Windows (Python 3.9) and my `.env` file has my infura and my etherscan token. I am using it with no problem, but whenever I deploy a contract with the `publish_source = True` my contract is verified(again, no problem). The thing is, if I go check on etherscan's page to see my API usage, I see no activity at all.
That raises the question of how is this contract being verified. Is it using my API keys but the monitor is broken?.

EDIT: I cannot embed a picture because of my reputation
[Etherscan API monitor showing no activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lDwY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for making this issue.There are 2 likely options:

1. It's a UI bug on Etherscan
2. Etherscan is realizing your bytecode is the same as another contract that is already verified, so it's having your contract be verified too.